# why is my Volley Response returning 'Failed' on my php file?

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have a php file. When I run it in Localhost like `http://localhost/UserDetails.php` it works as intended, no errors, getting details from `volleyLogin.php` and returning categories.

```
<?php

require_once('volleyLogin.php');

//Select from the cat_name column in the category table, check it against the User table and return values where things in the user_id
//column, in category table are equal to user_id in the user table, and where username in the usertable = "logged in user"

$resultSet = $con->query("SELECT category.cat_name FROM category INNER JOIN user ON category.user_id =
user.user_id WHERE user.username = '$username' ")
or die($con->error);
//$username = "ali" ;

if ($resultSet->num_rows > 0) {

        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {

$catname = $rows['cat_name'];
    // output data of each row
        //$catname = catname;

        echo "<p> Name: $catname </p>";
}}
        else {
   echo "0 results";
}
echo "userdetails.php works";

$con->close();

?>
```

When I upload the same file to my server and call it on my app with Volley (code below) I keep getting 'Failed' in my app. Do you know what I am doing wrong ? Strange the way it works on localhost and not on server, the same code. If I delete the code in `UserDetails.php` between `<?php` and `?>` then my response is 'Yes'. Any pointers would be a help, thanks.

```
public class ActivityUserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;

    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://12.345.67.89/UserDetails.php";

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME="username";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(textTitles);


        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        //do stuff here
                        textView2.setText("Yes");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        //do stuff here
                        textView2.setText("Failed");

                    }
                }){

        };

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

Comment: post your volley response.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi not sure what you mean. Do you mean something like putting echo "success" in my php file ?

Comment: Where does `$username` come from in your php script? Could it be that you have different `php.ini` configurations on localhost and your live server?

Comment: @gus42 $username is the logged in user in my app, taken at the volleyLogin.php stage. It works as intended on my live server.

Comment: Does `$username` come from a cookie, a session, a query parameter? What does your php script on your live server show when you call it from a browser running on a PC?

Comment: This might be a very stupid question, but are you sure that the `volleyLogin.php` is in the same directory? Because that might be a problem.

Comment: @gus42 I get `$username` like this : `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){$username = $_POST['username'];` It shows empty when run on a live server - probably because no $username has been posted?

Comment: @driftking9987 Yes, same directory

Comment: What does your php script on your live server show when you call it from a browser running on a PC?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi `response` comes up in red and when mouse is over it I see `Cannot resolve symbol 'response'`

Comment: public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { Log.d("error",error.toString());//add this line //do stuff here textView2.setText("Failed"); }

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi thanks, basically in logcat I get http://screencast.com/t/icid7Jg9Z

Comment: is your mobile device and the laptop on same network. Also try to open this url on your browser.

Comment: check your server IP.

Comment: Yes, ip address is correct and mobile and laptop on same network.

Comment: Have you tried my answer... Wat did it return on the logcat

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Wasn't getting anything significant in logcat, as it was a php problem. I've learnt the best way to see php related errors on an apache server are to check var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ActivityUserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;

public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://12.345.67.89/UserDetails.php";

public static final String KEY_USERNAME="username";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(textTitles);


    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    //do stuff here
                  Toast.maketext(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textView2.setText("Yes");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //do stuff here
                   Toast.maketext(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textView2.setText("Failed");

                }
            }){

    };

 // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


}
```

Try this. And post your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

This question helped me :
[PHP 500 Internal Server Error when calling Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370621/php-500-internal-server-error-when-calling-volley)

I dug deeper into the log files on my Apache server. In fact, one of my variables wasn't defined in the php files I was having problems with.

In my Apache error log I was getting :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in /var/www/html/UserDetails.php on line 8
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/html/UserDetails.php on line 8
```

In the problem file, `UserDetails.php`, I have:

```
require_once('volleyLogin.php');
```

And in `volleyLogin.php` I have :

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');
```

I thought that by requiring `volleyLogin.php` in my `UserDetails.php` it would also require the variables of `dbConnect.php`into the scope of my `UserDetails.php`, but this isn't the case.

In my `UserDetails.php` I changed this :

```
require_once('volleyLogin.php');
```

to this :

```
require_once('volleyLogin.php');
require_once('dbConnect.php');
```

And now it's working ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //do stuff here
                    textView2.setText("Failed");

                }
            }
```

To:

```
 new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    //do stuff here
                    textView2.setText("Failed" + error.toString());

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any response headers in your php file, so basically you server can interpret this different, and if response code != 200 you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

> If I delete the code in UserDetails.php between  then my
>   response is 'Yes'.

This and your screencast containing `Unexpected response code 500` points to an error in your `UserDetails.php` script.

> Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Because you only show a part of the script (`volleyLogin.php` is missing) no further hint on your code can be given.

The first thing I would do is check the error log of your live web server.

Furthermore I would write a simple html page to test the `UserDetails.php` script on your live server. Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="UserDetails.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="myusername">
    <input type="submit" value="Test">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Only when this test shows the desired result I would continue to implement the Android part.

> Strange the way it works on localhost and not on server, the same
>   code.

The different behaviour of the script on your localhost comparing to the live web server could be the result of different configurations of the web server daemons on either platform (e.g. php.ini, apache2.conf, etc. depending on the web server you use).